# Fire a SQL Server trigger once for parent or child updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

Our database has a parent table and multiple child tables for 1 to many relationships. The parent table has an UPDATE INSERT trigger so that when data is modified a 'count' of fields with data added in the current row is updated.

I would also like data INSERT DELETE or UPDATE on related records in the child tables to trigger an update of this count. So I put a trigger on each child table and it updates the count on the parent table. But when in a single transaction rows are inserted/deleted into multiple child tables then the count procedure will be fired multiple times. Is there a method to avoid this? I am looking for a single trigger only fired once for updates across multiple tables, but that has access to the inserted/deleted primary key ids for the union of all modified tables.

Comment: You can't have a single trigger span multiple tables.  Use a another table to store your counts and join to it when needed.

Comment: Triggers fire per statement, so you can't optimize updating the counts from that side. You could, I suppose, do something like using [`CONTEXT_INFO()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx) as a means to communicate between your transaction and the triggers. At the start of the transaction you would set a value indicating that your code will handle updating the counts. The triggers would still fire, but notice the flag is set and not perform any actions. Before ending the transaction you would reset the flag and update the counts, e.g. with a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks HABO that's confirmed what I suspected. I don't think triggers are really appropriate in this instance.

Comment: FWIW, you may want to look at the [`rowversion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) datatype. You may be able to use it to help with determining which rows in various tables have (possibly) changed during the course of a transaction. It's worth knowing about even if it doesn't help with your current challenge.